# How do I make an http request using cookies on flutter?

Tags: android, http, cookies, flutter

I'd like to make an http request to a remote server while properly handling cookies (eg. storing cookies sent by the server, and sending those cookies when I make subsequent requests). It'd be nice to preserve any and all cookies

for http request I am using

```
static Future<Map> postData(Map data) async {
  http.Response res = await http.post(url, body: data); // post api call
  Map data = JSON.decode(res.body);
  return data;
}
```

Comment: To parse the cookies sent by the server, you can use this package: https://pub.dev/packages/sweet_cookie_jar

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Here's an example of how to grab a session cookie and return it on subsequent requests. You could easily adapt it to return multiple cookies. Make a `Session` class and route all your `GET`s and `POST`s through it.

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

    class Session {
      Map<String, String> headers = {};
    
      Future<Map> get(String url) async {
        http.Response response = await http.get(url, headers: headers);
        updateCookie(response);
        return json.decode(response.body);
      }
    
      Future<Map> post(String url, dynamic data) async {
        http.Response response = await http.post(url, body: data, headers: headers);
        updateCookie(response);
        return json.decode(response.body);
      }
    
      void updateCookie(http.Response response) {
        String? rawCookie = response.headers['set-cookie'];
        if (rawCookie != null) {
          int index = rawCookie.indexOf(';');
          headers['cookie'] =
              (index == -1) ? rawCookie : rawCookie.substring(0, index);
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Just Question how you'll call it in a widget.

Comment: thantks for that, working great ! I used this solution, I just changed the class as a Singleton so I can acces one instance in my widgets

Comment: why do you get only the first substring before ' ; ' of the cookie? for example, in this cookie: "OCENTRIC_COOKIE=1; path=/;Secure;HttpOnly", what is after ' ; ' is not important?

Comment: The bits after the semi are instructions to you regarding when you should return the cookie. For example, it may only be relevant to certain path subsets. The instructions are not part of the cookie and should not be sent back to the server.

Comment: Was wondering why 'Set-Cookie' didn't work, it was actually 'set-cookie'. Postman and even the backend code uses 'Set-Cookie', is there a reason why it is lower case in dart/flutter?

Comment: Per the RFC all headers are case insensitive, though many servers are non-compliant. For ease of comparison, Dart forces them all to lower case.

Comment: What is that "index" bit at the end for? Can't I just do `headers['cookie'] = response.headers['set-cookie']`?

Comment: @daraul it's to chop off the bit after the semicolon (if present) - see the discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50299253/flutter-http-maintain-php-session/50299669#50299669

Comment: Hey, @RichardHeap can you please look into it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73133740/401-unauthorized-error-in-flutter-but-works-fine-in-postman

Comment: @RichardHeap just came across this post and one example before your comments mentions a cookie with the httpOnly flag. You don‘t seem to be bothered by that; can flutter mobile thus simply read httponly cookies via the response headers? I‘ve just posted a question about that as I would need to know if that works only in certain contexts (test mode etc) or only on specific devices, or if it works globally..? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78023348/httponly-session-cookies-can-be-read-accessed-within-flutter

Answer (score 23):

I have improved the Richard Heap's solution to be capable to process multiple 'Set-cookies' and multiple cookies.

In my case, the server returns multiples 'Set-cookies'. The http package concatenate all the set-cookies headers in one header and separate it by comma (',').

```
class NetworkService {

  final JsonDecoder _decoder = new JsonDecoder();
  final JsonEncoder _encoder = new JsonEncoder();

  Map<String, String> headers = {"content-type": "text/json"};
  Map<String, String> cookies = {};

  void _updateCookie(http.Response response) {
    String allSetCookie = response.headers['set-cookie'];

    if (allSetCookie != null) {

      var setCookies = allSetCookie.split(',');

      for (var setCookie in setCookies) {
        var cookies = setCookie.split(';');

        for (var cookie in cookies) {
          _setCookie(cookie);
        }
      }

      headers['cookie'] = _generateCookieHeader();
    }
  }

  void _setCookie(String rawCookie) {
    if (rawCookie.length > 0) {
      var keyValue = rawCookie.split('=');
      if (keyValue.length == 2) {
        var key = keyValue[0].trim();
        var value = keyValue[1];

        // ignore keys that aren't cookies
        if (key == 'path' || key == 'expires')
          return;

        this.cookies[key] = value;
      }
    }
  }

  String _generateCookieHeader() {
    String cookie = "";

    for (var key in cookies.keys) {
      if (cookie.length > 0)
        cookie += ";";
      cookie += key + "=" + cookies[key];
    }

    return cookie;
  }

  Future<dynamic> get(String url) {
    return http.get(url, headers: headers).then((http.Response response) {
      final String res = response.body;
      final int statusCode = response.statusCode;

      _updateCookie(response);

      if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode > 400 || json == null) {
        throw new Exception("Error while fetching data");
      }
      return _decoder.convert(res);
    });
  }

  Future<dynamic> post(String url, {body, encoding}) {
    return http
        .post(url, body: _encoder.convert(body), headers: headers, encoding: encoding)
        .then((http.Response response) {
      final String res = response.body;
      final int statusCode = response.statusCode;

      _updateCookie(response);

      if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode > 400 || json == null) {
        throw new Exception("Error while fetching data");
      }
      return _decoder.convert(res);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me to retrive multiple cookies

Comment: Thanks this helped me. There is a slight bug while you split the rawCookie on '='; it doesn't work when there are empty strings in the split. Following fix helped me.

    rawCookie.split('=').where((s) => s.isNotEmpty).toList(growable: false)

Comment: Also ignore the cases while comparing path and expires -
if (key.toLowerCase() != 'path' && key.toLowerCase() != 'expires') {
        return {key: value};
      }

Comment: The answer does not take into account when there is any '=' in the value part of the cookie. I have to change _setCookie method:
if (rawCookie.length > 0) {
 int idx = rawCookie.indexOf("=");
 if (idx >= 0) {
  var key = rawCookie.substring(0, idx).trim();
  var value = rawCookie.substring(idx+1).trim();
  if (key == 'path' || key == 'expires' || key == 'domain' || key == 'SameSite') return;
  cookies[key] = value;
 }
}

Answer (score 17):

I've published a small flutter library called [requests](https://github.com/jossef/requests) to assist with cookie-aware http requests.

```
dependencies:
  requests: ^3.0.1
```

Usage:

```
import 'package:requests/requests.dart';

// ...

// this will persist cookies
var r1 = await Requests.post("https://example.com/api/v1/login", json: {"username":"...", "password":"..."} ); 
r1.raiseForStatus();

// this will re-use the persisted cookies
var r2 = await Requests.get("https://example.com/api/v1/stuff"); 
r2.raiseForStatus();
print(r2.json()['id'])
```

find out more about [requests](https://github.com/jossef/requests)

Comment: Thanks a lot sir! Your package worked perfectly for me!

Comment: Hi, I am using graphql server and flutter_graphql package from here https://github.com/zino-app/graphql-flutter. Any idea on how I can use this package

Comment: @Jossef hi, is there a way to send a second request without terminating first request? I'm having an issue dealing with a cookie that has expire time "session"

Comment: @CharukaHS please open an issue -> https://github.com/jossef/requests/issues
add your request response detailed example

Comment: seems to have old dependencies can't use this

Comment: @JossefHarushKadouri will this store the cookie in local storage? Say I run both the post and the get requests mentioned here and close the app and run only the get request (without making the post request), will Requests.get be able to use the previous cookie? If not , what is to be done save the cookie locally ?

Comment: Hey @JossefHarushKadouri Can you please look into it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73133740/401-unauthorized-error-in-flutter-but-works-fine-in-postman

Comment: requests: ^4.7.0 Not works for me, I need to handle session and cookies

Answer (score 5):

I migrated [larly's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53991733/11084704) to nullsafety.
Also added 'put' function.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


class NetworkService {
  final JsonDecoder _decoder = const JsonDecoder();
  final JsonEncoder _encoder = const JsonEncoder();

  Map<String, String> headers = {"content-type": "application/json"};
  Map<String, String> cookies = {};

  void _updateCookie(http.Response response) {
    String? allSetCookie = response.headers['set-cookie'];

    if (allSetCookie != null) {
      var setCookies = allSetCookie.split(',');

      for (var setCookie in setCookies) {
        var cookies = setCookie.split(';');

        for (var cookie in cookies) {
          _setCookie(cookie);
        }
      }

      headers['cookie'] = _generateCookieHeader();
    }
  }

  void _setCookie(String? rawCookie) {
    if (rawCookie != null) {
      var keyValue = rawCookie.split('=');
      if (keyValue.length == 2) {
        var key = keyValue[0].trim();
        var value = keyValue[1];

        // ignore keys that aren't cookies
        if (key == 'path' || key == 'expires') return;

        cookies[key] = value;
      }
    }
  }

  String _generateCookieHeader() {
    String cookie = "";

    for (var key in cookies.keys) {
      if (cookie.isNotEmpty) cookie += ";";
      cookie += key + "=" + cookies[key]!;
    }

    return cookie;
  }

  Future<dynamic> get(String url) {
    return http.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: headers).then((http.Response response) {
      final String res = response.body;
      final int statusCode = response.statusCode;

      _updateCookie(response);

      if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode > 400) {
        throw Exception("Error while fetching data");
      }
      return _decoder.convert(res);
    });
  }

  Future<dynamic> post(String url, {body, encoding}) {
    return http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: _encoder.convert(body), headers: headers, encoding: encoding).then((http.Response response) {
      final String res = response.body;
      final int statusCode = response.statusCode;

      _updateCookie(response);

      if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode > 400) {
        throw Exception("Error while fetching data");
      }
      return _decoder.convert(res);
    });
  }

  Future<dynamic> put(String url, {body, encoding}) {
    return http.put(Uri.parse(url), body: _encoder.convert(body), headers: headers, encoding: encoding).then((http.Response response) {
      final String res = response.body;
      final int statusCode = response.statusCode;

      _updateCookie(response);

      if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode > 400) {
        throw Exception("Error while fetching data");
      }
      return _decoder.convert(res);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If it wasn't a problem, I use dio and cookiejar.

Just add these dependencies in your `pubspec.yaml`:

```
dependencies:
  dio: ^4.0.4
  dio_cookie_manager: ^2.0.0
  cookie_jar: ^3.0.1
```

Here's an example to use it. Make sure you run it as a flutter script, and not a dart script.

```
import 'package:cookie_jar/cookie_jar.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:dio_cookie_manager/dio_cookie_manager.dart';


void main() async {
  var dio =  Dio(BaseOptions(
      connectTimeout: 10000,  // in ms
      receiveTimeout: 10000,
      sendTimeout: 10000,
      responseType: ResponseType.plain,
      followRedirects: false,
      validateStatus: (status) { return true; }
  ));   // some dio configurations

  dio.interceptors.add(CookieManager(CookieJar()));

  var firstResponse = await dio.get(
      "https://somewebsite.com/get_login_info");
  print(firstResponse.data);

  var loginResponse = await dio.post(
      "https://somewebsite.com/login",
      data: FormData.fromMap(
          {
            'username': 'YourUsername',
            'password': 'YourPassword',
          }
      ));  // cookies are automatically saved
  print(loginResponse.statusCode);

  var nextResponse = await dio.get(
      "https://somewebsite.com/get_login_info");
  print(nextResponse.data);
}
```

an example output:

```
{"is_logged_in": 0}
302
{"is_logged_in": 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found best solution to handle cookies for redirect also

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

class CustomHTTPClient{
  final HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
  Map<String, String> _cookies = Map();

  CustomHTTPClient(){
    _client.connectionTimeout = Duration(seconds: 10);
  }

  Future<String> get(String url, {int maxRedirect = 3}) async {
    final parsedUrl = Uri.parse(url);
    return await _client.getUrl(parsedUrl)
        .then((HttpClientRequest request) {
      request.followRedirects = false;
      _beforeRequest(request);
      return request.close();
    }).then((HttpClientResponse response) async {
      _afterResponse(response);
      if(response.isRedirect && maxRedirect > 0){
        return await response.drain().then((value) => get(parsedUrl.resolve(response.headers.value('location')).toString(), maxRedirect: maxRedirect - 1));
      }
      return response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
    }).catchError((error, stack){
      print(error);print(stack);
    });
  }

  void _beforeRequest(HttpClientRequest request){
    request.headers.set(HttpHeaders.acceptEncodingHeader, 'gzip, deflate, br');

    // Set cookie
    final String rawCookies = _cookies.keys.map((String name) => '$name=${_cookies[name]}').join('; ');
    if(rawCookies.isNotEmpty) request.headers.set(HttpHeaders.cookieHeader, rawCookies);
  }

  void _afterResponse(HttpClientResponse response){
    response.headers.forEach((String name, List<String> values){
      if(name == 'set-cookie'){ // Get cookies for next request
        values.forEach((String rawCookie){
          try{
            Cookie cookie = Cookie.fromSetCookieValue(rawCookie);
            _cookies[cookie.name] = cookie.value;
          } catch(e){
            final List<String> cookie = rawCookie.split(';')[0].split('=');
            _cookies[cookie[0]] = cookie[1];
          }
        });
        return false;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you need a format, then here it is:

```dart
Map<String, String> headers = {
   'cookie': 'cookie1=$data1;cookie2=data2;cookie3=data3'
};
```

can access by calling cookie1,2,3

Answer (score 0):

Depending if you use flutter web or mobile there different ways to get cookies

for flutter web you just have to:

- set credentials to true on front
- in my case add "'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true" to your header on server, I use Dart on back-end (Alfred framework)
- check whether origin from your server match with your host:port on front

Your browser will do the job and resend automatically your cookies.

you can define a specific port when launching the app with this command
- "flutter run -d chrome --web-port 5555"

But for mobile you have to make some tricks

I use Dio package to easily define an onResponse/onRequest function and a conditional import to avoid compilation fail. (withCredentials option is available only on web unfortunately)

If you want to use default http class

you just have to make your own onResponse/onRequest function

**NetworkConfig.dart**

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

import '../../../constants/url_paths.dart';
import 'get_net_config.dart'
    if (dart.library.io) 'mobile_net_config.dart'
    if (dart.library.html) 'web_net_config.dart';

class NetworkConfig {
  final _client = getClient()
    ..options = BaseOptions(
      baseUrl: url,
      connectTimeout: const Duration(seconds: 5),
      receiveTimeout: const Duration(seconds: 6),
    );

  Dio get client => _client;

  final Map<String, String> headers = <String, String>{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  };
}
```

*I use another class to do my get, post... which extends NetworkConfig*

**get_network_config.dart**

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

    Dio getClient() => throw UnsupportedError('[Platform ERROR] Network client');
```

**web_network_config.dart**

```
import 'package:dio/browser.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

Dio getClient() =>
    Dio()..httpClientAdapter = BrowserHttpClientAdapter(withCredentials: true);
```

**mobile_network_config.dart**

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:<projet_name>/data/data.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

// CLIENT
Dio getClient() => Dio()
  ..interceptors.add(InterceptorsWrapper(
    onRequest: (options, handler) async {
      options.headers['cookie'] = await localData.read('cookie');

      return handler.next(options);
    },
    onResponse: (response, handler) {
      response.headers.forEach((name, values) async {
        if (name == HttpHeaders.setCookieHeader) {
          final cookieMap = <String, String>{};

          for (var c in values) {
            var key = '';
            var value = '';

            key = c.substring(0, c.indexOf('='));
            value = c.substring(key.length + 1, c.indexOf(';'));

            cookieMap[key] = value;
          }

          var cookiesFormatted = '';

          cookieMap
              .forEach((key, value) => cookiesFormatted += '$key=$value; ');

          await localData.write('cookie', cookiesFormatted);

          return;
        }
      });

      return handler.next(response);
    },
  ));
```

***localData is my wrapper for flutter_secure_storage (to persiste cookies locally)***

---

if you use the default Client() class you can also set credentials like this

```
import 'package:http/http.dart';

Client getClient() => BrowserClient()..withCredentials = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a Singleton Class as for me creating instance of ApiService without singleton was reinitializing everything.

I also created a custom post function which will be used for all post requests to be used in the project. Similarly get and other functions can also be created.

**api_service.dart(singleton class)**

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class ApiService {
  static final ApiService _singleton = ApiService._internal();
  factory ApiService() {
    return _singleton;
  }

  ApiService._internal();

  String? sessionCookie;

  Future<void> setSessionCookie(http.Response response) async {
    String? rawCookie = response.headers['set-cookie'];
    if (rawCookie != null) {
      int index = rawCookie.indexOf(';');
      sessionCookie = (index == -1) ? rawCookie : rawCookie.substring(0, index);
    }
  }

  Future<http.Response> post(String url, Map<String, String?> body) async {
    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(url),
        headers: {'Cookie': sessionCookie ?? ''},
        body: body,
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        setSessionCookie(response); // Updating the session cookie here
      }

      return response;
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception('Error making POST request: $e');
    }
  }
}
```