# How do I can iterate cookie values from http response?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using rest API in my flutter app. For further request I need JSESSIONID which I received from my profile API. I successful got response but I need guide to iterate cookie value.

I followed following steps:

```
final response = await http.get(
      strURL,
      headers: {
        "Authorization": basicAuth,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
    );

    String rawCookie = response.headers['set-cookie'];
    print('rawCookie $rawCookie');
```

As print raw cookie it is printing details:

```
flutter: rawCookie __cfduid=d5bbe3f8a131478a78ae996e636cca0401544177738; expires=Sat, 07-Dec-19 10:15:38 GMT; path=/; domain=.rayz.ch; HttpOnly,JSESSIONID=6AD6698C5BFC90F1D089696A955E6824; Path=/; HttpOnly
```

I can iterate it by substring but I want to iterate it with a proper way. So please guide me on this.

Comment: you can start by coding a model class for rawCookie then you code a named constructor which will take your cookie string and populate your model properties

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make an http request using cookies on flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52241089/how-do-i-make-an-http-request-using-cookies-on-flutter)

Comment: @RichardHeap In that question it is not mentioned how I can iterate that. There is only mentioned and I followed that one even to receive cookies. 
Now I want to iterate cookies separately.

Comment: Using package http you need to split the cookies yourself by `split`ing the `String` on comma.

Answer (score 4):

With package:http you need to split the cookie string yourself using `String.split`. If you want to use the underlying http client, that gives you a pre-parsed list of cookies, for example:

```
  HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();
  HttpClientRequest request = await _httpClient.postUrl(Uri.parse(url));
  request.headers.set('content-type', 'application/json');
  request.add(utf8.encode(json.encode(jsonMap)));
  HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();
  print(response.cookies); // this is a List<Cookie>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code which runs perfectly and if any key does not have value, then it shows range error. But as your doubt, this code is running fine.

```
var headersList = response.headers['set-cookie']!.split(";");
for(var kvPair in headersList){
  var kv = kvPair.split("=");
  var key = kv[0];
  var value = kv[1];

  if(key.contains("session_id")){
    print(value);
  }
}
```

Comment: `set-cookie` contains a comma-separated list, not a semicolon-separated list, of cookies. This won't work properly and it can't be fixed by simply replacing `;` with `,` because the cookie itself may also contain `,`.