# How to persist a cookie in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, cookies

i'm making an app in Flutter and i need to send a cookie on the header to access my web API.

However, i'm not having any sucesss.

Here is my code.
How can i persist a Cookie in flutter?

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class XsrfToken {
  static Future<String> getXsrf(String getJwt) async {
    var url = 'https://www.myservice.com/api/v1/api.php';

    var decode = json.decode(getJwt);

    var header = {"Content-Type": "application/json"};

    Map params = {"token": decode};

    var _body = json.encode(params);

    var response = await http.post(url, headers: header, body: _body);

    print('Responde status ${response.statusCode}');
    print('Responde body ${response.body}');

    var xsrf = response.body;

    var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString("TokenXSRF", xsrf);

    return xsrf;
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make an http request using cookies on flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52241089/how-do-i-make-an-http-request-using-cookies-on-flutter)

Comment: I am trying to reproduce in my code. But so far I haven't been able to

Comment: Ok, then: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53687711/10659482

Comment: Could you show me in the code please?

Answer (score 2):

To add cookies to hearders.

```dart
var cookie1 = 'xyz';
var cookie2 = 'abc';

var headers =  {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          'Cookie': 'myCookie1=$cookie1; mycookie2=$cookie2',
        };
```

For retrieving cookies

```dart
var cookiesData = response.headers['set-cookie'];
if (cookiesData != null) {
    Map _cookies = _formatCookies(cookiesData);
    // Do your logic
}
```

You will get this in a long String.

Here is what I personally use for formating

```
Map _formatCookies(String cookiesData) {
  Map cookies = {};

  if (cookiesData.contains('cookie1')) {
    List at = RegExp(r'(cookie1)(.*?)[^;]+').stringMatch(cookiesData).split('=');
    cookies['cookie1'] = at[1];
  }

  if (cookiesData.contains('cookie2')) {
    List rt = RegExp(r'(cookie2)(.*?)[^;]+').stringMatch(cookiesData).split('='); 
    cookies['cookie2'] = rt[1];
  }

  return cookies;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but how can i retreave this cookie from the server response?

Comment: What i need is obtain the cookie that the server is sending to me.

Comment: _format function I personally use for jwt tokens, not sure about the RegExp for other strings.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try to reproduce here.

Answer (score 0):

String session = response.headers['set-cookie'].toString().split(";").first.split('=').last;