# Maintain flask_login session in flutter

Tags: flutter, flask, flask-login

Soo...I have an app with `flask` backend and `flutter` frontend. It utilizes `flask_login` to manage users. Problem is - I don't know how to maintain session on client side. Flutter client gets response from server, but I don't see any token, or user_id inside.

So far, I've tried to parse responce, with no luck and I've used solution from [How do I make an http request using cookies on flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52241089/how-do-i-make-an-http-request-using-cookies-on-flutter)
also, without success.

Server-side https://github.com/GreenBlackSky/COIN/blob/master/api_app/app/login_bp.py

Client-side https://github.com/GreenBlackSky/coin_web_client/blob/master/lib/session.dart

Maybe, using `flask_login` was not such a good idea after all..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with the `request_loader` approach? You can log in from Flutter client using a url argument and the `Authorization` header. Quoting from the [documentation](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#custom-login-using-request-loader),

> For example, to support login from both a url argument and from Basic Auth using the Authorization header:
>
> ```
> @login_manager.request_loader
> def load_user_from_request(request):
>
>     # first, try to login using the api_key url arg
>     api_key = request.args.get('api_key')
>     if api_key:
>         user = User.query.filter_by(api_key=api_key).first()
>         if user:
>             return user
>
>     # next, try to login using Basic Auth
>     api_key = request.headers.get('Authorization')
>     if api_key:
>         api_key = api_key.replace('Basic ', '', 1)
>         try:
>             api_key = base64.b64decode(api_key)
>         except TypeError:
>             pass
>         user = User.query.filter_by(api_key=api_key).first()
>         if user:
>             return user
>
>     # finally, return None if both methods did not login the user
>     return None
> ```

---

If you don't want to use `flask_login` anymore, I would suggest [flask_jwt_extended](http://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for your case. Note that authentication will be carried out using JWT tokens instead of sessions.

Basically, you would need to create three routes: one for creating access and refresh tokens when the user logged in, one for refreshing the expired access token with the refresh token and one for removing the tokens when the user logged out. Then you would protect your API endpoints with the `@jwt_required` decorators.

Please refer to the documentation for detailed implementation.

Comment: using `request_loader` requires to get `api_key` during registration and then sending this key as argument with each request, right? I saw this example, but, apparently, made wrong conclusions at that time)

Comment: I used flask_jwt_extended at the end, becouse it gives me more fine control over the authentification process, thank you)