# Cookies don't work in dart but curl generated by CurlLoggerDioInterceptor works in shell

Tags: dart, curl, cookies

I have in my Flutter project APIs that use cookies and they don't work. I have enabled the interceptor that generates the curl:

`CurlLoggerDioInterceptor (printOnSuccess: true)`

with the following result:

```
curl -i \
        -H "Accept: application / json" \
        -H "Connection: keep-alive" \
        -H "cookie: ci_session = uv0hts7fb8us0r7m5vvaa64p4o89u9he" \
        -H "Authorization: 1652292531" \
        "http://xxxxx.it"
```

And this works on shell. I don't understand, why the curl generated by Dart code works and the code itself doesn't work?

Regarding the code I've used all the solutions in this link (dio_cookie_manager, NetworkService, HTTP request instead of dio...) [How do I make an http request using cookies on flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52241089/how-do-i-make-an-http-request-using-cookies-on-flutter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Dio is not possible, but with the following library yes:

```
flutter_curl: ^0.1.1
```